# error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6

Tags: debian, package-management

When I try to update my system, it returns the following error:

`serj@debianochka:~$ sudo apt update`

> /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error
>   while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory /usr/lib/apt/methods/http:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory
>   /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory Reading package lists... Done E: Method http
>   has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http returned an error code
>   (127) E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly E:
>   Method http has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http returned an
>   error code (127) E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start
>   correctly E: Method http has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http
>   returned an error code (127) E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did
>   not start correctly E: Method http has died unexpectedly! E:
>   Sub-process http returned an error code (127) E: Method
>   /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly E: Method http has
>   died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127) E:
>   Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly E: Method
>   http has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http returned an error code
>   (127) E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly E:
>   Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease
>   E: Failed to fetch
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease
>   E: Failed to fetch
>   http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease   E:
>   Failed to fetch
>   http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-backports/InRelease
>   E: Failed to fetch
>   http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease   E:
>   Failed to fetch
>   http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease   E:
>   Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

If i try to install any program, then error:

`serj@debianochka:~$ sudo apt install git`

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done
>   git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u1). You might want
>   to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following
>   packages have unmet dependencies:  dnsmasq-base : Depends: libnettle6
>   (>= 3.4~) but it is not going to be installed 
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going to
>   be installed  iputils-ping : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not going
>   to be installed  libarchive13 : Depends: libnettle6 but it is not
>   going to be installed  libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libnettle6 but it is
>   not going to be installed  libgnutls30 : Depends: libnettle6 (>= 3.4~)
>   but it is not going to be installed  libhogweed4 : Depends: libnettle6
>   (= 3.4.1-1) but it is not going to be installed  librtmp1 : Depends:
>   libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed  wget : Depends:
>   libnettle6 but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies.
>   Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a
>   solution).

apt --fix-broken install **NOT Working**

If i input: 
`serj@debianochka:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`

> Reading package
>   lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The following
>   additional packages will be installed:   libnettle6
>   /usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory E: Method http has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http
>   returned an error code (127) E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did
>   not start correctly

[image: full error]

Comment: You should copy&paste the command and its output as text and format it as a code block. I suggest to put a line `~~~` before and after it. You can try to download a `libnettle6` package matching your distribution and version and manually install it with `dpkg`. See also https://superuser.com/questions/1386209/how-to-solve-this-dependencies-apt-fix-broken-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @Bodo, it looks like you reached a point where `apt` removed `libnettle` which is required to run ... `apt`.

Try to download the corresponding package for your architecture using https://packages.debian.org and install it manually using `dpkg -i <path to the .deb>`.

You can try with `wget <URL>` or `curl <URL> > libnettle.deb`.

If both curl and wget fail because they also depends on libnettle, then, try downloading it from another PC and use SSH to copy it.

Then, re-run `apt-get install --fix-broken`.